# C++11 introduced exception constructors taking `const char*`. But why?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, language-lawyer

[Standard library defect #254](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#254) which covers the addition of new exception constructors:

```
std::logic_error::logic_error(const char* what_arg);
std::runtime_error::runtime_error(const char* what_arg);
// etc.
```

gives as rationale the idea that storing `std::string`s opens up some cans of worms relating to potentially problematic memory allocation.

However, [following initiation of a discussion by orlp in the Lounge](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22089407#22089407), it strikes me that unless the standard were to mandate that `what_arg` were only ever a string literal (or a pointer to some other buffer of static storage duration), it would have to perform a copy of the C-string anyway in order to maintain the well-definedness of member function `what()`.

That's because:

```
void bar() {
   char buf[] = "lol";
   throw std::runtime_error(buf);
}

void foo() {
   try {
      bar();
   }
   catch (std::exception& e) {
      std::cout << e.what() << '\n';   // e.what() points to destroyed data!
   }
}
```

But I cannot see any such mandate. In fact, whether exception objects deep copy `what_arg` or not appears to be entirely unspecified.

If they *do*, then a large chunk of the rationale for adding the overloads in the first place (eliminating additional allocations) appears to be entirely vacuous.

Is this potentially a standard defect, or am I missing something here?
Is this just a case of "programmer: don't pass dangling pointers anywhere"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This allows (or at least is apparently intended to facilitate--see more below) the implementation to eliminate copies in cases where it can detect (by means that are not themselves standardized) that what's being passed is a string literal or something else with static storage duration.

Just for example, let's assume a compiler pools all string literals together into a range delimited by `__string_literals_begin` and `__string_literals_end`. Then somewhere inside the constructor for `std::exception` it could have code on the general order of:

```
namespace std {
    exception::exception(char const *s) { 
        if (in_range(s, __string_literals_begin, __string_literals_end)) {
            stored_what = s;
            destroy_stored_what = false;
        }
        else {
            stored_what = dupe(s);
            destroy_stored_what = true;
        }
        // ...
    }

    exception::~exception() {
        if (destroy_stored_what)
            delete_string(stored_what);
}
```

The final comment in the linked DR states:

> [ Oxford: The proposed resolution simply addresses the issue of constructing the exception objects with const char* and string literals without the need to explicit include or construct a std::string. ]

So based on the comments at the time, the committee was aware that these overloads didn't fill all needs, but did address (what was at least perceived as) a need.

It's (almost) certainly true that an implementation *could* provide these overloads even without their being mandated by the standard--nonetheless, the committee seems to have been convinced that adding them was useful, primarily (if not exclusively) for the case outlined above--doing only a shallow copy when a string literal is passed to the ctor.

Comment: Aren't implementations allowed to add constructors for optimizations like this regardless of the standard adding them, as long as behavior doesn't change?

Comment: @orlp: Yes, as the defect text says.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then I'd say -1 and unaccept, since this does not explain why this addition was made.

Comment: Doesn't the DR argue for reference-counting it?

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm still a bit confused. The defect linked seems to be a random collection of implementation ideas - not all valid, until finally arbitrarily deciding to add this constructor. If the rationale is as you say - a really strong suggestion for a particular implementation, I would expect the rationale given in the defect is a clear and concise suggestion to implement it. However it is not.

Comment: @orlp The C++ spec community has to find the smallest solution to support these special cases.  It could have stood up and mandated an entire set of special memorized string behaviors, but it is very hard to do so.  Compilers already handle these strings differently.  Instead, they made the smallest nudge they could: constructors that don't obviously require a malloc.

Comment: When I code for situations like this, I find a large difference between "theoretically, a very smart compiler could realize that this special case std::string doesn't need a malloc, because it doesn't change the behavior" and "The spec community thew me a bone, and wrote a special constructor whose sole job is to open up a hole where compilers can do smart optimizations."  In the later case, I can at least rely on the argument that the spec community thinks an optimization should occur.  In the former, I don't really have a leg to stand my argument on.

Comment: See also the vile word `volatile`, which almost never means what you think it should mean, by the spec.  However, every compiler I know of treats it more conservatively, making it act like you thought it should act.  The spec definition isn't good enough to do anything, but it leaves a clear hole where you can expect compilers to do "the best they can."  `inline` is in a similar boat

Comment: I agree with @orlp that this doesn't answer the question. Also, is there any reason `std::string` could not do a similar trick to shallow-copy if it can detect a string literal and avoid malloc? It would also need to be careful to do a copy-on-write if someone wants to modify a `std::string` initialized with a string literal, but that's easy enough. My point is that this optimization/trick can already be employed in a way so as to avoid malloc in `std::except`, even without the new exception constructors.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: search the interwebs for several years of past discussion of COW strings in C++. The problem is that because of the guarantees on validity of pointers to elements of the string, COW is forbidden. If you first get a read-only pointer to an element, then modify the string using non-const `operator[]` and assignment, your pointer doesn't reflect this change but the standard says it hasn't been invalidated. It's also not clear that `string::operator[]` is permitted to throw `bad_alloc`, I can't remember the verdict on that, so copy-on-access might also be forbidden :-)

Comment: ... so anyway, I don't think implementations can provide this functionality *just* by jiggering `string`. It has to be something specific to exceptions. I do believe, though, that even without a standard constructor a compiler could detect the idiom `exception(my_pointer)` and eliminate the intermediate `std::string` construction. I may be wrong.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, copy on access is also forbidden for `std::string` (in fact, I don't think even C++98 would have allowed it). The problem isn't really with maintaining maintaining iterator validity (as such) but with maintaining validity of iterator pairs. Obvious example would be when iterating from `s.begin()` to `s.end()`--if `*s.begin()` copied, then it wouldn't equal `s.end()` after the right number of increments, even though `s.begin()` and `s.end()` both remained valid individually.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it's THE reason, but one thing is that runtime_error guarantees that it's copy constructor won't throw, which indicates some sort of reference counted mechanism.

The additional constructor means that it will only have to make the one copy, from char* to the underlying mechinsm, rather than twice. Once into a string and then into the reference mechanism

Comment: How can a copy into a `string` (when constructing from `string`) guarantee `noexcept`?

Comment: @Walter The copy constructor is `noexcept`, not the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The defect's resolution solves a different problem. The bottom of the defect has this note:

> [ Oxford: The proposed resolution simply addresses the issue of constructing the exception objects with const char* and string literals without the need to explicit include or construct a std::string. ]

Answer (score 2):

How does libc++ handle this issue?

They currently use a ref-counted string to store the message:

```
class _LIBCPP_EXCEPTION_ABI logic_error
    : public exception
{
private:
    _VSTD::__libcpp_refstring __imp_;
```

Where `__imp_` is initialized as follows:

```
logic_error::logic_error(const string& msg) : __imp_(msg.c_str()) {}

logic_error::logic_error(const char* msg) : __imp_(msg) {}
```

This string, `__libcpp_refstring`, does allocate a new buffer when storing a new `char const*`:

```
explicit __libcpp_refstring(const char* msg) {
        std::size_t len = strlen(msg);
        _Rep_base* rep =
             static_cast<_Rep_base *>(::operator new(sizeof(*rep) + len + 1));
```

But, of course, the copy constructor of `__libcpp_refstring` does not allocate a new buffer.

(Yes, this doesn't answer the question, but it should shed some light on the issue I think. For example, if there were only a `std::string const&` ctor in `logic_error`, there had to be one additional allocation for the ref-counter.)

Comment: libstdc++ is a lot more complicated; it seems they have multiple cases (preprocesser switches) because their old `std::string` is COW, but the new one isn't.

Comment: As far as I can see, neither libstdc++ nor libc++ perform the optimization mentioned by @JerryCoffin.